# How to use github in android application?

Tags: android, json, github

I want to connect my android application into server through Json. is that possible to connect through github  I had referred this link http://developer.github.com/v3/  but i didn't get any idea about that?can any one explain.

Answer (score 0):

The following method brings you the data from URL.

```
public static JSONObject getJSONfromURL(String url, Context c) {
            url = url.trim();
            url = url.replace(" ", "%20");
            Log.i("getJSONfromURL", "URL From json functions: " + url);
            InputStream is = null;
            String result = "";
            JSONObject jArray = null;
            try {
                HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);

                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                is = entity.getContent();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.d("Json Functions", " The Xceptions are " + e.getMessage());
            }

            try {
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                        is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);

                String line = null, name = null;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {

                    name = line;
                }
                is.close();
                result = name;

            } catch (Exception e) {

            }

            try {
                if (result != null) {
                    jArray = new JSONObject(result);
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {

            }
            return jArray;
        }
```

Call this function as follows :

```
try {
            JSONObject json = JSONfunctions
                    .getJSONfromURL(Your URL,
                            Yourclassnname.this);
   }catch(Exception e)
{
}
```

Use AsyncTask to get the Json Result. Hope it helps

Comment: how to construct url in github?

Answer (score 0):

You can also use Volley, the latest Google AsyncHttpClient Api [check this [link](http://www.kpbird.com/2013/05/volley-easy-fast-networking-for-android.html)] or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17278866/android-volley-quickstart). I find it to be much simpler and easy to use for what you want to do. For example:

```
private RequestQueue reqQueue  = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);                              
private JsonObjectRequest jsObjRequest;

public void connectViaVolley(){
String servURL="https://api.github.com/repos/mojombo/jekyll/issues?state=closed"; //this URL is what is on GitHub already, so you can test with it

jsObjRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, servURL, null, new       Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

@Override
public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

//Handle any non-error response and parse the JSONobject
}
 }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

 @Override
 public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

//handle any errors here [no need for exceptions as Volley does this already]
                }
            });

    //actual network connection/request
 reqQueue.add(jsObjRequest);
    }
```